# Debug Fork with Visual Studio [C]

Tags: c, debugging, fork, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with a multi-process program in **C**.
I'm looking for a solution to debug fork() with VS Code (using GDB).
I have found "set follow-fork-mode child" but do not work (or I make something wrong).

I don't know how to debug this fork, and when I google it, nothing for visual studio code (only classic visual studio).

How to debug a fork ? access to stack call and variables ? (for **C**)
Thank you !

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you do not need this anymore, but I found a solution.

You can use gdb command:

```
set follow-fork-mode child
```

[there is a command description](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html)

You need to enter it into the debug console(Ctrl+Shift+Y) in this form:

```
-exec set follow-fork-mode child
```

And now, when you call the fork, the piece of code of the child will be executed.

Or, you can use [this method](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/511#issuecomment-283507115).

Also, it may be usefull to [attach to process](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-versus-attach-configurations) instead of step-by-step debug of forking processes.

Comment: Yeah I don't need it but maybe in the futur, I will test !

Comment: @Homper , good one, but how do you reverse it ?